# YouCompleteMe unavailable: requires Vim compiled with Python (3.8.0+) support

Tags: python-3.x, unix, vim, vim-plugin, youcompleteme

I would like to install the vim plug-in YouCompleteMe but after installing, when I launch Vim I get the warning:

```
YouCompleteMe unavailable: requires Vim compiled with Python (3.8.0+) support.
```

I know that I have Python 3.9.13 installed on my machine so I don't see what the issue is.

Could anyone help with this issue?

Comment: For better help, please [edit] your question to include your Vim distribution, version, and what feature flags it was compiled with (see `vim --version`).

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operative phrase in that error message is *"compiled with"*. It's not the version(s) of Python you have installed on your system that matter, but the version of Python that your Vim installation supports.

You can refer to the Installation section of [YouCompleteMe's README](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe#requirements) for what Vim runtimes are supported. You may be able to install a compatible version of Vim using your preferred package manager. Failing that, you can always [build Vim from source](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Neovim and solved it by installing [pynvim](https://github.com/neovim/pynvim).

It can be installed using `pip3 install pynvim`

Answer (score 0):

Just install "vim-python".

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).